# How can I merge multiple HTTP calls to one entity model in Angular

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

I have this scenario:

This interface represent the axis values.

```
export interface ChartModel {
    HorizontalElement: number,
    VerticalElement: number
}
```

I can have multiple charts in one plot, so I use this model.

```
import { ChartModel } from "./ChartModel";

export interface ResponseModel {
    PrimaryChart: ChartModel[];
    PreviousQuarterChart1: ChartModel[];
    PreviousQuarterChart2: ChartModel[];
    PreviousQuarterChart3: ChartModel[];
}
```

Now I have two API services that returns the data. One of them I have to call 3 times. How can I do to merge all the calls into one service method and that method returns only one result of type ResponseModel.

What i have is 3 elements like this one for each service call this is what i've called ChartModel:

```
[
    {
        "HorizontalElement": 0,
        "VerticalElement": 150
    },
    {
        "HorizontalElement": 1,
        "VerticalElement": 236
    },
    {
        "HorizontalElement": 2,
        "VerticalElement": 330
    }
]
```

And what i want to do is to concatenate the 3 responses in one object called ResponseModel.
Something like this:

```
[
[{"HorizontalElement":0,"VerticalElement":150},{"HorizontalElement":1,"VerticalElement":236},{"HorizontalElement":2,"VerticalElement":330}],
[{"HorizontalElement":0,"VerticalElement":150},{"HorizontalElement":1,"VerticalElement":236},{"HorizontalElement":2,"VerticalElement":330}],
[{"HorizontalElement":0,"VerticalElement":150},{"HorizontalElement":1,"VerticalElement":236},{"HorizontalElement":2,"VerticalElement":330}]
]
```

Comment: So, you have an array containing 3 arrays of ChartModel. All you need is `return { PrimaryChart: array[0], PreviousQuarterChart1: array[1], ... }`. Of course, we can't really figure out how to get 4 arrays out of an array which only has 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for Observable.forkJoin method 
(https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)
This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each.

Please, let me know if you need an example.

Comment: yes i've used it, but I can't figure out how to retrieve only one result of type ResponseModel, each service api returns ChartModel, when merged with fork, it returns ChartModel[] (array).

Comment: @Juanma edit your question, and post your code, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. You should have done that from the start.

Comment: You said that you have to create 3 requests. And each request return ChartModel. But could you explain me please is data similar to each field of ResponseModel?

Comment: I've edited my question, I need to merge all the responses from the service to one object and return it to the view

Comment: Did you use a simple variant?
   `const chartData  = new ResponseModel {
    PrimaryChart: response;
    PreviousQuarterChart1: response;
    PreviousQuarterChart2: response;
    PreviousQuarterChart3: response;
}`

Comment: I could solve my problem. I have taken a wrong approach to the solution, the problem was in the way I was subscribing to the forkJoin method.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution!